# concatenate two 232 strings and output as a single string

Tags: serial-port

I am trying to concatenate two 232 strings and output as a single string. I was wondering if an Arduino would provide me with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate strings in following method :

**By using + operator**

You can use a `string` datatype to represent a string.

```
String a("Hi,");
String b(" I am boss");
String op = a+b;
```

So the concatenated string will be in `op`. In this way you can implement concatenation.